# SFTP transfer results in ^M in the uploaded file

Tags: php, shell, ssh, sftp, phpseclib

I try to upload file from web PHP to shell server and run it with this command (phpseclib)

```
$sftp->put("$upload", "$imageupload", NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE)
```

It already uploaded but have `^M` in the file

This is my file before upload to server

> 12345
>
> 67890

Then this is file from shell server

> 12345^M
>
> 67890^M

What should I do with this problem? Have the way to use `sftp->put` and it's not have `^M`?

Comment: *ftp* clients usually have a setting for binary versus ascii, but I have not seen an `sftp` client which allows that choice.

Comment: I guess you are uploading a file created on a Windows pc to a Linux server and what you see the carriage return character. Check this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843495/what-does-m-character-mean-in-vim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are uploading a text file in Windows format to a Unix server.

Some Unix applications are not able to deal with Windows-style line endings.

The problem is generally resolved using a text mode transfer. But while the text mode transfer is widely supported by FTP clients and servers, it is supported by few SFTP clients and servers. It's definitely not supported by the phpseclib. The phpseclib supports SFTP protocol version 3 only. And the text mode is supported since SFTP protocol version 4 only.

So you need to convert the file to Unix format yourself *before* the upload.

For a conversion in PHP, see for example: [how to convert text file from DOS to Unix line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6925180/850848)

For more background, see also *my* article [Why are text file line breaks wrong after the file is transferred or edited?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_line_breaks)