# Cannot read json in PHP, need newline at the end of the text

Tags: php, json

So I have a json file inside my folder, but I cannot read it because it need an empty line at the end, how to solve that ?

I read my json in PHP using this :

```
$string = file_get_contents('ideb/NPWP.txt');
$json_a = json_decode($string, TRUE);
echo $json_a['header']['kodeReferensiPengguna'];
```

My json :

```
{
    "header": {
        "kodeReferensiPengguna": "",
        "tanggalHasil": "",
        "idPermintaan": "",
        "idPenggunaPermintaan": "",
        "dibuatOleh": "Dyta Alldilah",
        "kodeLJKPermintaan": "",
        "kodeCabangPermintaan": "",
        "kodeTujuanPermintaan": "",
        "tanggalPermintaan": "",
        "totalBagian": "1",
        "nomorBagian": "1"
    }
}
```

If I add newline at the bottom of the json there is no error

```
{
    "header": {
        "kodeReferensiPengguna": "",
        "tanggalHasil": "",
        "idPermintaan": "",
        "idPenggunaPermintaan": "",
        "dibuatOleh": "Dyta Alldilah",
        "kodeLJKPermintaan": "",
        "kodeCabangPermintaan": "",
        "kodeTujuanPermintaan": "",
        "tanggalPermintaan": "",
        "totalBagian": "1",
        "nomorBagian": "1"
    }
}
```

NOTE : My json file format is .txt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert the line endings of a text file from DOS to Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925180/how-to-convert-the-line-endings-of-a-text-file-from-dos-to-unix)

Comment: What is the output of `json_last_error_msg`?

Comment: NULL Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded..

Comment: I did not expect that error lol..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to @NikitaLeshchev..

Using :

```
$string = file_get_contents('ideb/NPWP.txt');
$json_a= mb_convert_encoding($string , 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
$json_a = json_decode($string, TRUE);
echo $json_a['header']['dibuatOleh'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The key kodeReferensiPengguna has no value. print dibuatOleh key there is value. it is working.

```
$string = file_get_contents('ideb/NPWP.txt');
$json_a = json_decode($string, TRUE);
echo $json_a['header']['dibuatOleh'];
```

Comment: ya it is working, turn out when I copy the json file from my document and copy it to my laravel folder somehow it is not working, but when i create the json file directly in my laravel folder it's working fine..

any solution ??

Comment: i think issue in path. are you putting correct path of file ?

Comment: nothing wrong with the path, my original json file which is from my document has no newline at the end of the text and I cannot read it, but when I create new file on laravel folder, copy paste the json text, it's working fine. smh...